# Record UIAlertView button tap with MonkeyTalk

Tags: testing, monkeytalk

I'm trying to write automated test script for iOS application using MonkeyTalk.

The problem is that I cannot record action when button inside UIAlertView is pressed.
It seems like MonkeyTalk doesn't even register there is a UIALertView dialog present and just gives me command: `UITextEffectsWindow * Tap`
I tried with `Button ButtonName Tap`, `Button #1 Tap` and `Button 1 Tap`  (#1 is the index of button).

Did anybody had this kind of problem and solved it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after a lot of tries I managed to record UIAlertView button event.
It's actually very simple after all. This is how you record UIAlertView button event:
Just add

```
UIAlertViewButton ButtonTitle Tap
```

in script.

Comment: Can u help me out with this question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20394209/monkeytalk-not-recognizing-uitextfield-input-event