# MonkeyTalk not recognizing UITextfield input event

Tags: ios, monkeytalk, uitextinput, monkey-testing

I am using Monkeytalk v1.0.62 and its not recognizing textfield input event inside the UIAlertview. If I type any text inside the textfield, it shows nothing while recording or in playback. It seems like the monkeytalk wont recognize UITextfield input or does it?

Answer (score 1):

To record text input in UIAlertView text field try this:

> UIAlertSheetTextField * EnterText "Some text"